# differentiate by a differential

Tags: calculus, differential

This is a difficult question to phrase so I will show it mathematically. I am trying to differentiate something through chain rule but I am not sure if my steps are correct.

Let

$f(\theta) = \sin(\theta)$

Is it possible to obtain the answer to this:

$\frac{d }{d \dot{\theta}}f(\theta)$

I have tried to do the following:

Let
$ z = \dot{\theta}$
 so

$ \theta = \int{z} $

$\frac{d \sin{ \int{z} } }{dz} =  z\cos{ \int{z} } $

Which gives me the answer as

$= \dot{\theta} \cos{\theta} $

Is this correct? Is it even possible to differentiate in this manner?

Comment: You seem to be arriving at a chain rule type result, but by taking a sequence of dubious steps.  The answer would be correct if the question were about treating the derivative of $\sin \theta$ with respect to $t$ when $\theta = \theta(t)$ is a function of $t$.  As you suggest, your difficulty lies mostly in stating this question, which hinders the steps you take to solve it.

Comment: Just an observation: if you are trying to solve Euler-Lagrange equations, i.e. $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}L(t,\dot\theta,\theta)-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{\theta}}L(t,\dot\theta,\theta)=0$$ you should know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot\theta}$ is a physicist's notation which stands for the partial derivative of $L(t,x,y)$ with respect to the second variable. In that context, for instance, what is meant is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot\theta}(5t+\dot\theta^2\theta+\sin\theta)=2\dot\theta\theta$$

Answer (score 0):

The symbolism $\frac{d f(\theta)}{d \dot{\theta}}$ is very strange (or crazy ?)

How can we understand it ?

$\dot{\theta}=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$

$d\dot{\theta}=d\left(\frac{d\theta}{dt}\right)=\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}dt=\ddot{\theta}dt$

$\frac{d f(\theta)}{d \dot{\theta}}=\frac{d f(\theta)}{\ddot{\theta}dt}=\frac{1}{\ddot{\theta}}\frac{df(\theta)}{dt}$

In case of $f(\theta)=\sin(\theta)$ this leads to :  $\frac{d \sin(\theta)}{d \dot{\theta}}=\frac{1}{\ddot{\theta}}\frac{d\sin(\theta)}{dt}=\frac{1}{\ddot{\theta}}\cos(\theta)\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{\dot{\theta}}{\ddot{\theta}}\:\cos{\theta}$

That is stretching a point to say the least.

.

In addition after the judicious orion's comment :

Of course if the typing was :
$\quad \frac{\partial f(\theta \:,\:\dot{\theta}\:,\:\ddot{\theta},...) } {\partial \dot\theta}\quad$ there would be no ambiguity at all.

Comment: That's a typical expression you get from Euler-Lagrange formalism, but you need to write a partial derivative to be pedatic.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you get from Euler-Lagrange formalism, then you need to write a partial derivative, and there is no $\dot{\theta}$ in the expression, so the result is $0$.